# How do I convert a DataView to an ObjectDataSource

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, sharepoint-2010

I am currently binding a SPGridView to a DataView. I would like to bind to an ObjectDataSource instead using the .DataSourceID property of SPGridView so that I can get filtering on my grid which doesn't work with a DataView (from what I have read). Is there an easy way to instantiate an ObjectDataSource from a DataView? I found some related questions but none of the answers showed enough code context to allow me to figure out how to do this.

Here is how my code looks now and what I am looking to do:

```
DataSet myDataSet;
myDataSet = populateDataFromDatabaseBasedOnSomeSearchParameters(startDate, endDate);
DataView myGridDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0];

// Somewhere in here convert to an ObjectDataSource so that I can bind using DataSourceID instead and get filtering to work

SPGridView myGridView;
myGridView.DataSource = myGridView;

myGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to convert a DataView to an ObjectDataSource in C#.
However, you could use the same DataSource for both the DataView and GridView.

```
myDataSource.DataSource = someDataSource;
myGridView.DataSource = someDataSource;
myDataSource.DataBind();
myGridView.DataBind();
```

Then, when your DataView changes, update the DataSource and rebind your GridView.

```
private void myDataView_OnListChanged(object sender, 
    System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs args)
{
    //Update the DataSource someDataSource
    myGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Hope this helps.